# Calling external function from async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm somewhat new to JS and working with an existing forked library (which is very complicated and poorly documented) - so please bear with me.

I'm working on a mining pool system, and specifically adding a feature where users can set a custom payout amount instead of the lower pool limit. I've already sorted writing that value for a users worker address into redis.

What I'm trying to do now is add logic that will:

1. Use the worker Address that did work to see if they set a custom payout value (my external function below)
2. If it's set, some logic to determine if they should be paid immediately or add it to their balance

The existing waterfall script is here: https://github.com/mardock2009/Ravencoin-Pool/blob/master/libs/paymentProcessor.js#L575

Before the waterfall, i'm adding a function similar to this (i've tried many iterations):

```
getCustomPayoutAmount = function(worker, cback) {
    var logger = loggerFactory.getLogger('PaymentProcessing', 'getCustomPayoutAmount');

    var redisClient = redis.createClient(portalConfig.redis.port, portalConfig.redis.host);             
    logger.debug('Getting custom Payout for worker: %s', worker);
    var payoutAmount = new BigNumber(0);

    redisClient.hget('ravencoin:workers:customPayoutAmount', worker,  function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            logger.error('Error getCustomPayoutAmount: %s', error);
            payoutAmount = 0;
        }
        logger.debug('Got custom payout amount for worker: %s, Payout Amount: %s', worker, result);
        if (result > 10) {
            payoutAmount = new BigNumber(result);
            logger.debug('Parsed Float Amount: %s', payoutAmount);
        } else {
            logger.debug('Else lower than: %s', payoutAmount);
            payoutAmount = new BigNumber(0);
        }       
    });
    cback( new BigNumber(payoutAmount));    
};
```

Then at around line 575, i'm calling it (maybe?):

```
                    var customPayoutAmount = new BigNumber(0);

                    getCustomPayoutAmount(worker, function(returnCustomPayoutAmount) {
                        logger.debug('Callback customPayoutAmount = %s', returnCustomPayoutAmount);
                        customPayoutAmount = returnCustomPayoutAmount;
                    });

                    logger.debug('PP> customPayoutAmount = %s', customPayoutAmount);
```

And then finally, some if/elseif logic to handle the different cases:

```
if (toSend.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(minPayment)) {

                        if (toSend.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(customPayoutAmount) && !customPayoutAmount.isZero()) {
                            //Amount Sent is higher than the custom amount set for this worker. Pay it out.
                            logger.debug('PP> Worker %s have their custom minimum payout amount: (%s above minimum %s)', w, toSend.toString(10), customPayoutAmount.toString(10));
                            totalSent = totalSent.plus(toSend);              
                            logger.debug('PP> totalSent = %s', totalSent.toString(10));
                            var address = worker.address = (worker.address || getProperAddress(w));              
                            logger.debug('PP> address = %s', address);
                            worker.sent = addressAmounts[address] = toSend;
                            logger.debug('PP> worker.sent = %s', worker.sent.toString(10));
                            worker.balanceChange = BigNumber.min(worker.balance, worker.sent).multipliedBy(new BigNumber(-1));
                            logger.debug('PP> worker.balanceChange = %s', worker.balanceChange.toString(10));

                        } else if (toSend.isLessThan(customPayoutAmount) && !customPayoutAmount.isZero()){
                            //Amount is higher than the minimum payment but not higher than the custom amount set for this worker. Add it to their balance.
                            //Did not meet the pool minimum, no custom amount. Add to balance.
                            logger.debug('PP> Worker %s have not reached minimum payout from their custom set payout amount threshold %s', w, customPayoutAmount.toString(10));
                            worker.balanceChange = BigNumber.max(toSend.minus(worker.balance), new BigNumber(0));
                            logger.debug('PP> worker.balanceChange = %s', worker.balanceChange.toString(10));
                            worker.sent = new BigNumber(0);
                            logger.debug('PP> worker.sent = %s', worker.sent.toString(10));
                            if (worker.balanceChange > 0) {
                                if (balanceAmounts[address] != null && balanceAmounts[address].isGreaterThan(0)) {
                                    balanceAmounts[address] = balanceAmounts[address].plus(worker.balanceChange);
                                } else {
                                    balanceAmounts[address] = worker.balanceChange;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if (toSend.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(minPayment) && customPayoutAmount.isZero()) {
                            //Meets the pool minimum payment, no custom amount. Pay out based on the pool minimum payment.
                            logger.debug('PP> Worker %s have reached minimum payout threshold (%s above minimum %s)', w, toSend.toString(10), minPayment.toString(10));
                            totalSent = totalSent.plus(toSend);              
                            logger.debug('PP> totalSent = %s', totalSent.toString(10));
                            var address = worker.address = (worker.address || getProperAddress(w));              
                            logger.debug('PP> address = %s', address);
                            worker.sent = addressAmounts[address] = toSend;
                            logger.debug('PP> worker.sent = %s', worker.sent.toString(10));
                            worker.balanceChange = BigNumber.min(worker.balance, worker.sent).multipliedBy(new BigNumber(-1));
                            logger.debug('PP> worker.balanceChange = %s', worker.balanceChange.toString(10));
                        }

                        
                    } else {
                        //Did not meet the pool minimum, no custom amount. Add to balance.
                        logger.debug('PP> Worker %s have not reached minimum payout threshold %s', w, minPayment.toString(10));
                        worker.balanceChange = BigNumber.max(toSend.minus(worker.balance), new BigNumber(0));
                        logger.debug('PP> worker.balanceChange = %s', worker.balanceChange.toString(10));
                        worker.sent = new BigNumber(0);
                        logger.debug('PP> worker.sent = %s', worker.sent.toString(10));
                        if (worker.balanceChange > 0) {
                            if (balanceAmounts[address] != null && balanceAmounts[address].isGreaterThan(0)) {
                                balanceAmounts[address] = balanceAmounts[address].plus(worker.balanceChange);
                            } else {
                                balanceAmounts[address] = worker.balanceChange;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The main issue I'm having is I cant get values back from redis calling it inside the waterfall. I'm assuming because it's async andIi'm not writing async code - which also causes it to not necessarily run in order when I need the values.

Again, I know this is a mess and I'm probably going about this all wrong, so hopefully someone has some insight for this poor noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [async.each()](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each)

```js
function(workers, rounds, addressAccount, callback) {
  var trySend = function(withholdPercent) {
    ...
    async.each(workers, function(worker, callback) {
      ...
      getCustomPayoutAmount(worker, function(customPayoutAmount) {
        ...
        if (toSend.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(minPayment)) {
          if (toSend.isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(customPayoutAmount) && !customPayoutAmount.isZero()) {
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
        callback();
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      if (Object.keys(addressAmounts).length === 0) {
        logger.info('PP> No workers was chosen for paying out');
        callback(null, workers, rounds, []);
        return;
      }
      ...
      daemon.cmd('sendmany', [addressAccount || '', addressAmounts, 1, ""], function(result) {
        ...
      }
    });
  };
  trySend(new BigNumber(0);
}
```

and In 'getCustomPayoutAmount', 'cback()` should be called within the callback of 'redisClient.hget()' like below

```js
getCustomPayoutAmount = function(worker, cback) {
    ...

    redisClient.hget('ravencoin:workers:customPayoutAmount', worker,  function(error, result) {
        ...
        cback(payoutAmount);   
    });
     
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! Think I got this in the right order in the code, giving it a try now. It takes about 2hrs to fully generate a block to test against in testnet, fingers crossed!

Comment: OK I Think I totally did this wrong, I uploaded the file to GH - mind taking a look and seeing wtf i did wrong? Sorry if i'm not understanding this at all. - https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/paymentProcessor.js#L605

Running this days the worker is just [object Object] and then fails the code below. logs:

PP> toSend = 4975
Entered Async.Each for worker: [object Object]
/paymentProcessor.js:679 if (shareAmounts[address] && shareAmounts[address].isGreaterThan(0)) {
ReferenceError: address is not defined

Comment: You have to replace "for loop" block with "async.each()". Please refer https://github.com/cuspymd/rvnpool/commit/04075fa52b464f9063aa1b4dd2c0b917336ec9ae?diff=split

Comment: Thank you! I didnt expect you to actually edit the fixes in! Appreciate that! One question, the for loop was used to iterate over multiple workers that could get a pay out, and used to use the variable "w" to represent each worker that could be in that array. I'm now getting ReferenceError: w is not defined, since it no longer exists. Should that be workers[worker] now?

Comment: Actually looks like i should just be using "worker" for each iteration. I updated the file to use worker instead (https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/paymentProcessor.js) but still getting errors, I uploaded the log here: https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/logs.log

Items of note, WATERFALL> roundShare = [object Object] used to not show an object in the log,  The worker is not showing the address (Workers Passed through: [object Object]) and then of course the app is dying at "then()" (Cannot read property 'then' of undefined)

Comment: About "then" error, I think you are using old aysnc.js version(<3). Please change not to use a promise like https://github.com/cuspymd/rvnpool/commit/31de4c18d478f89b7cdced848730d13de2be4adc.

Comment: Yeah, the pool  uses very old deps and nodejs 8.17 unfortunately. Would love to pay someone to update all this unreadable code at some point. 

The new code you posted gets it closer, its still not passing the payment address through, and shows up in the log as object. I updated the log at https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/logs.log

I've also attached a log of what this looks like when it works here (original code in production) - https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/logs_working.log - and thank you so much again for helping here!!

Comment: "workers" is an object not an array. Let's change "async.each(workers, function(worker, callback) {" into "async.eachOf(workers, function(worker, w, callback) {".

Comment: Thanks, and "w" would be what I call to get each individual worker address?

Comment: Yes. Its name is the same as original code.

Comment: OK, I only ask because in the original code the first thing it does in the for loop is set var worker = workers[w]; (i.e. the worker string to worker), so what would "worker" refer to in the first param of the function "async.eachOf(workers, function(worker, w, callback) {"?

Comment: You can refer https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachOf. The callback of "async.eachOf()" invoked with (item, key, callback). The "key" is a key of "workers" and the "item" is a value of "workers[key]".

Comment: Shouldnt that be  async.eachOf(workers, function(workers, w, callback) {  then? (both of them called "workers" not "worker" in the function? In the example on what you linked, validConfigFileMap is a variable accessible above the eachOf. in this case "worker" doesnt exist anywhere.

Comment: Nope. You misunderstood the example code. Our callback "function(worker, w, callback)" is the same as "function parseFile(file, key, callback)" in the example.

Comment: Thank you again, I think I understand now - sorry again since I am still learning JS (my native language is C#). Trying this out now, will take about an hour for some new blocks to come through to run against.

Comment: This seems to be working!! Thank you so much! I would have gone to chat instead of all this back and forth but I dont have enough rep. Really appreciate the help with this project.

Comment: Thank you too. Hope the project goes well.

Comment: One more question, this seems to be more cosmetic than anything but the data would be good to have. When a custom minimum payout is set, and the payout is under that it transfers to a balance. However when this happens, its marked in the stats with the key of undefined instead of the workers address. An example is line 18 here https://github.com/devdevdevdev1/rvnpool/blob/main/json_balance_undefined.json#L18, and also the amount of shares done on line 21.  These seem to be set in the payment processor on line 644 and 668 and then formatted at line 718. No idea why the key isn't setting.

Comment: Let's move the statement assigning the variable "address" to the beginning of the "async.eachOf()" function.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to comment earlier, I did indeed realize that on my own - tested and works! Thanks again!